# How to handle errors with bulk requests

Tags: elasticsearch, error-handling, elasticsearch-bulk-api

I am using Elasticsearch bulk API to send a lot of documents to index and delete at once. If there is an error for one document, other documents will be indexed or deleted successfully. And this leads to wrong state of data in elasticstore because in my case documents are kind of related to each other. I mean if one document's field has some value then there are other documents which should also have same value for that field. I am not sure how I can handle such errors from Bulk requests. Is it possible to rollback a request in any way? I read similar questions but could not get solution on handling such cases. Or instead of rollback, is there any way to send data only if there is no error? or something like dry run of request possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the question but will answer for whoever runs across a similar scenario in the future.

After executing the Elasticsearch (ES) bulk API aka `BulkRequest`, you get a `BulkResponse` in return which consists of one or more `BulkItemResponse`. `BulkItemResponse` has a method `isFailed()` which will tell you if that action failed or not. In your case, you can traverse all the items in the response if there are failures and handle failed responses as per your requirement.

The code will look something like this for `Synchronous` execution:

```
val bulkResponse: BulkResponse = restHighLevelClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
bulkResponse.iterator.asScala
.filter(_.isFailed)
.foreach(item => { // your logic to handle failures })
```

For `Asynchronous` execution, you can provide a `listener` which will be called after the execution is completed. You have to override `onResponse()` and `onFailure()` in this case. You can read more about it at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-document-bulk.html

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The solution shared above to use BulkResponse output is basically to handle next batch requests. What if I want to break the batch processing at the position where any request failed in the batch. We are sending bulk events which are related to each other. Example of my issue:  Batch(E1- E10), if batch fails at E5. I don't want E6-E10 to process because they are related. I want immediate response in that case.